# *ngfor angular2 integrate in laravel

Tags: angular

I use for the firsst time angular , I build a API to get data from laravel backEnd in json array object with the service:

```
getFoodsByCat(id :number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://livrer/api/menu/' +id)
    .map(
        (response: Response) => { return response.json().foods;
         }
    );}
```

In my component I use this service like that:

```
export class FoodsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() food : Food ;
foods: Food[];

  constructor(private foodService: FoodService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
     onGetFoodsByCategorie( id){

    this.foodService.getFoodsByCat(id)
    .subscribe(
    (foods: Food[])=> this.foods = foods,
    (error : Response)=> console.log(error)
    );
      } }
```

But in the template I use

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
<li class="resp-tab-item" (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(1)">Panninis</li>
<li class="resp-tab-item" (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(2)">Tajines</li>
<li class="resp-tab-item" (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(3)">Sandwichs</li>
<li class="resp-tab-item" (click)="onGetFoodsByCategorie(4)">Pizzas</li>
</ul>
     <li *ngFor= "let food of foods" [food]="foods">
    //some style and data
    </li>
```

I get this Error :

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'food' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("


<li *ngFor= "let food of foods" [ERROR ->][food]="foods">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="thumbnail-menu-modern">  
"): FoodsComponent@26:32
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its related with this (you have an input so I mean u modify data)
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/2-way-data-binding-to-an-array-element-in-an-ngfor-ionic-2-rc1/67977/2

> I think that your list is reloaded again by ngFor when you change one field value, and that is why it is losing the focus. You can add a trackBy to determine if the list must or must not be reloaded. The code below seems to solve the issue:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index; trackBy: customTrackBy">
    <ion-label stacked primary>An item</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="itemList[i]"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
And in the .ts file:



customTrackBy(index: number, obj: any): any {
return index;
}
```

Adapted to your code :) :

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let food  of foods ; let i = index; trackBy: customTrackBy">
    //some data
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And add the method 'customTrackBy' in your .ts file

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error just because of this thing

```
[food]="foods"
```

food is not a property of li element just remove it to solve the error simply use loop like this

```
<li *ngFor= "let food of foods">
  //some style and data
 <li>
```

E.g you are using food as input your component and in loop the variable is same food as food change one of them either